# Product Sorting Not working Properly

Tags: magento-1.8, sorting

I have created product attribute named Custom Sort `Catalog >> Attributes >> Manage Attributes`

`Catalog Input Type for Store Owner` as `Text Field`
`Input Validation for Store Owner` as `Decimal`

and i'm using this attribute as default sort for my products
`Catalog >> Manage Categories` 
in category edit page under `Display Settings` i have set `Default Product Listing Sort By` as my attribute `Custom Sort`

but the issue is magento sorts the products in following way
`1`
`11`
`2`
`3`

I would like to sort products in following way
`1`
`2`
`3`
`11`

Please guide me how to achieve this

Comment: please reindex from admin

Comment: reindex makes no difference :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the sorting works properly. If your attribute has the type "text" the sorting will work on strings.
So from the strings point of view `11 < 2`.
You need to have the attribute as `decimal`.
The `Input Validation for Store Owner` fields means just a simple validation. It does not mean that the attribute type will be decimal.
The value is still saved as `varchar`.

[See this](http://inchoo.net/magento/programatically-create-attribute-in-magento-useful-for-the-on-the-fly-import-system/) on how to create a product attribute programatically.

If you want to create the attribute from the UI and have the type 'decimal', I'm not sure what type you have to choose. I think `price` but not sure.

Comment: Thanks @Marius, i got it, i should give sort order like `a` `b` .. `z` .. `za` `zb`